# Convert a list of sheets from a workbook into a dataframe and bind by rows

Tags: r, excel

I am reading an excel workbook with sheets of data running from December 2017 to September 2019. I have imported the spreadsheet with all the workbooks and would like to transpose all the sheets and bind all the rows into one dataset.

Below is my code.

```
names(SheetList)

> [1] "Dec. 17"   "Jan. 18"   "Feb. 18"   "March 18"  "April 18"  "May
> 18"    "June 18"   "July 18"   "Aug. 18 "  
> [10] "Sept. 18"  "Oct. 18" 
> "Dec.18"    "Jan-19"    "Feb-19"    "Mar-19"    "Apr-19"    "May-19"  
> "June-19"   
> [19] "July-19"   "August-19" "Sept.-19"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame()
for (sheet in names(SheetList)){
    df <- Sheetlist[[sheet]] %>%
        t() %>%
        rbind.data.frame(df, .)
}
```

Assuming SheetList is a list of dataframes.

Comment: Please note the loaded packages, `library(dplyr)... etc`

Answer (score 0):

Transpose then row bind:

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(SheetList, t))
```